# Prepared statement only executes once, until I delete my broser's cache

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, prepared-statement

For a list of events, I dynamically create buttons for entering whether the user can attend the event or not. I add EventListeners to the buttons, so that they execute prepared statements when clicked.
The "no"-button works at the first time, inserting a row into table 'absences', but if the user clicks "no", then "yes" (which deletes the row) and then "no" again, the second "no" does not insert a row into the database again.

Here's how the EventListeners for the "no"-buttons are created (while looping through the date_ids):

```
btn_no.addEventListener('click', (function(date_id) {
    return async function() {
        var return_value;

           var data = {date_id: date_id,
                        user_id: user["user_id"],
                        isAbsent: 1};
            return_value = await preparedInsert("absences", data);
        

        if (return_value != "") { // error
            try {alert("Error: " + JSON.parse(return_value));}
            catch {alert("Error: " + return_value);}
            return;
        }


        // .. here follows styling of the affected dates in the list
    }
})(date_id));
```

The js-function preparedInsert() looks like this:

```
function preparedInsert(table_name,data) {
    var t = encodeURIComponent(table_name);
    var d = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));

    return new Promise( resolve => {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                resolve(this.responseText);
            }
        }
        request.open("GET", "includes/preparedInsert.inc.php?t="+t+"&d="+d);
        request.send();
    } );
}
```

Lastly, preparedInsert.inc.php:

```
<?php
    include "dbh.inc.php"; // get $conn

    $table_name = $_GET["t"];
    $data       = json_decode($_GET["d"]);

    $types = "";
    $columns = "";
    $placeholders = "";
    $values = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $types .= "s";
        $columns .= $key . ",";
        $placeholders .= "?,";
        $values[] = $value;
    }
    $columns = substr($columns, 0, -1); // delete trailing comma
    $placeholders = substr($placeholders, 0, -1); // delete trailing comma
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name ($columns) VALUES ($placeholders)";
    // INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...);

    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e;
    }

    if ($conn->error) {echo json_encode($conn->error);}
```

No errors are thrown anywhere: I tried adding `$driver = new mysqli_driver(); $driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;`, `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of preparedInsert.inc.php but got no errors.

Every function seems to run as intended: I tried adding console-logging or echoing *everywhere* and it always works.

The "no"-button only works again when I clear my browser's cache, so I'd guess it has to do with the caching of prepared statements? But I don't understand them well enough to see why it wouldn't execute the same query a second time.

Also, it works when testing on my local XAMPP, but not on the actual online-server. Sadly, there are no errors being logged by my serverhost either when this problem occurs.

For some reason, the equally-created "yes"-button works perfectly twice. In case it hints to a notable difference, here's its EventListener:

```
btn_yes.addEventListener('click', (function(date_id) {
    return async function() {
        var absence = user["absences"][date_id];

        var condition = {absence_id: absence["absence_id"]};
        var return_value = await preparedDelete("absences", condition);

        if (return_value != "") { // error
            try {alert("Error: " + JSON.parse(return_value));}
            catch {alert("Error: " + return_value);}
            return;
        }

        // .. here follows styling the affected dates in the list
    }
})(date_id));
```

..and the preparedDelete.inc.php that's opened in the quasi-identical js-function preparedDelete():

```
<?php
    include "dbh.inc.php"; // get $conn

    $table_name = $_GET["t"];
    $conditions = json_decode($_GET["c"]);

    $types = "";
    $placeholder_string = "";
    $values = [];
    foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
        $types .= "s";
        $placeholder_string .= $key . " = ? AND ";
        $values[] = $value;
    }
    $placeholder_string = substr($placeholder_string, 0, -4); // delete trailing AND
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE $placeholder_string";
    // DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE key1 = ? AND key2 = ? AND...

    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
        echo "Fehler: " . $e;
    }

    if ($conn->error) {echo json_encode($conn->error);}
```

Comment: Why do you catch exceptions? Please don't do that. You are leaking sensitive information to your users. Just let the PHP error handler log these exceptions on the server.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that danger, thank you for mentioning it!

Comment: _"only works again when I clear my browser's cache, so I'd guess it has to do with the caching of prepared statements?"_ - browsers can't "cache" prepared statement, all they can cache is the responses to specific HTTP requests. XMLHttpRequest with a GET request often leads to unexpected caching problems (the browser _not_ making a new request) - but since you are making a request that _modifies_ data on the server side, this should be a POST to begin with (and with that, there are usually no such caching issues.)

Comment: Well, that fixed it! Thank you so much <3 I'm fairly new to StackOverflow, how can I give you credit for solving my problem when you only posted a comment instead of an answer? 

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing part of CBroe's comment:

*"XMLHttpRequest with a GET request often leads to unexpected caching problems (the browser not making a new request) - but since you are making a request that modifies data on the server side, this should be a POST to begin with (and with that, there are usually no such caching issues.)"*

That fixed it! (Answering my own question since CBroe didn't post an answer themselves, sorry if that's wrong)

Comment: I think posting the answer is okay, but your first and last line are kind of just noise that isn't relevant to the answer. I would just post the answer itself.